# Linux "Set" command usage in Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to use Linux "set" command in Chef recipe, I tried it using "execute" resource, in-order to set positional parameters on the node server. It shows no error, after running the convergence 'chef-client'. But when I check it on the node, to echo out the value for the position variable (Ex: "echo $2"), there is no value displayed. How can I resolve it, is they any other process or I'm getting it wrong? Below are the exact lines in the recipe

```
execute "temp_password" do
  command "set `cat temppasswd.txt`"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`set` is not a command, it's a shell built-in function. I think you are trying to say you want to set some environment variables for use later in the recipe based on the content of a file. Unfortunately this isn't how Unix works, setting an environment variable in a subprocess (bash) has no effect on its parent (chef-client). I also don't know what you mean by "positional parameters" in this context. If you can provide more details about your actual goal I can provide more help, but as written the best I can tell is that no part of your question is actually a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. A temporary password for a user is generated in the logs. I did grep the line content, with the temp. password and pasted the output to a file (in my case it's tempasswd.txt). I need to use this password initially for setting up a permanent password later. So I can use "set" function to set the positional parameters (variables) on the content of the file which includes temp. password. Later we can use the particular variable with the temp. password value in it by passing the argument.

Comment: For example if the temp. password is at 7th position in the file content, we can echo out to verify the value, say echo $7. I want to use $7 variable later in setting up the permanent password. This is working out when I tried it on the Linux test server by executing a shell script.
So, I need a way to automate this process in Chef by using a resource like "bash" in the recipe or some other way?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to read and process the file from Ruby code, but you could use a `bash` or `script` resource as long as everything you need to do with an environment variable is in one script. Once control passes back up to Chef, the env vars are lost.

Comment: I'm a bit new to chef. I work majorly on Linux scripts. I'm trying to get hands-on chef by automating the process I've done using shell scripts. Please correct my below ruby code in recipe

Comment: I can't correct the code you included as it is not a complete description of your problem. I've already told you how to fix it yourself.

Comment: I'm new to chef. I work majorly on Linux scripts. I'm trying to get hands-on chef by automating the processes I've done using shell scripts to develop the services on the node. Below is the code I'm trying in getting the temporary password (which is the last word in the .txt file) to the variable "pass" in recipe                                                                      file='tempasswd.txt'                                                                            pass = file.split.last #and then if the value is stored in "pass", I can you it in my script further by passing #{pass}.